# PHP помогите написать условие для Validator из Form обршается к базе данных SQl

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть Форма, которую валидирую

```
class CreditBankFieldset {

    'creditorId'=> [
                    'required'          => false,
                    'allow_empty'       => true,
                    'continue_if_empty' => true,
                    'filters' => [
                        ['name' => \App\Input\Filters\ToString::class],
                        ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
                        ['name' => 'StripTags'],
                    ],
                    'validators' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'StringLength',
                            'options' => [
                                'max' => 255
                            ],
                            
                        ],
                        [
                            'name' => \App\Input\Validators\IsCreditRequired::class,                        
                            'options' => [
                                'settingsService' => $this->settingsService,
                                'messages' => [
                                    'Error' => 'SEPA direct debit is not activated. Add an "Incassant ID" or use Mollie direct-debit.',
                                ]
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
}

public function isValid($value)
    {                               
        $result = $this->options['settingsService']->getSettings();
        informDeveloper(print_r($result['mollieDirectDebit'],true));
        if($value == false){
        } 
        if($result['mollieDirectDebit'] == false){
            $this->error(self::ERROR);
            return false;    
        }
        

        return true
```

Мне нужно проверить условие с значениями `$value` и поле `mollieDirectDebit`, чтобы валидировалось именно это поле и выдавало ошибку.

Comment: informDeveloper(print_r($result['mollieDirectDebit'],true)); Ввожу для проверки у себя в консоле. Мне приходит массив ['mollieDirectDebit'] с значением 1

Comment: В первую очередь вам нужно отредактировать вопрос и вынести вопросы из code block.

Comment: @DiMithras  а по поводу условия в коде что посоветуете?                                                        public function isValid($value)
        {                               
            $result = $this->options['settingsService']->getSettings();
            if($value == false){
            } 
            if($result['mollieDirectDebit'] == false){
                $this->error(self::ERROR);
                return false;    
            }
            
            return true

Answer (score 0):

```
public function isValid($value)
    {                               
        $result = $this->options['settingsService']->getSettings();
   
   
        if($result['mollieDirectDebit'] == false && $value = false){
            $this->error(self::ERROR);
            return false;    
        }
        

        return true
```